# Pass a Macro to a param in Airlfow

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to pass a date parameter to my sql templated in BigQueryOperator, but it seems that is not possible to pass a macro as parameter, the code:

```
    for days in range(0, 3):  # load last 3 days
    
            date_path = "{{{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -{days}), '%Y-%m-%d',  '%Y/%m/%d') }}}}".format(
                days=days
        )
```

```
    bq_to_gcs = BigQueryOperator(
                task_id="task_id...",
                sql=path.join("queries", "query.sql"),
                params={
                    "schema": BQ_SOURCE_DATA_SET_ID,
                    "date_path": date_path,
                }
```

And I'm calling the parameter in my query.sql  like:
**{{params.date_path}}**

but what I'm receving is this:
**{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, - 0), '%Y-%m-%d',  '%Y%m%d') }}"**

I cannot pass the macro directly in my sql code because I need the variable "days" to calculate the date.

Someone knows how could I do this?

Edit: I also tryed to pass the days as paramater, like:

```
    params={
                        "schema": BQ_SOURCE_DATA_SET_ID,
                        "day": days,
                    }
```

and calculate the date inside the sql using:
**{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, - {{params.days}}), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y%m%d') }}"**
but i got a error because I'm using {{}} inside another {{}}

Comment: Only templated fields will resolve the string to real value. [`query_params` isn't templated](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.13/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html). `sql` is templated so you can use `date_pass` in it directly.

Comment: But how could I pass directly in sql code?
I cannot use like this way:
{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, - {{params.days}}), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y%m%d') }}

Comment: I am guessing you think it's not possible because of `{{ params.days }}`. You can do something like `sql=f"YOUR QUERY {{{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, -{params.days}), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y%m%d') }}}}"`